# Django filter name__icontains not working

Tags: django, postgresql, macos, web, apple-m1

I have some model with name field as:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Name', db_index=True)
```

I want to filter my records by some string WITHOUT REGISTERING, for example a record with name "Apple" should be found by the strings "Apple", "apple", "aPPle", "ApPpLe" and so on.
I use:

```
results = Page.objects.filter(name__icontains=query)
```

But it doesn't work. Various combinations like:

```
results = Page.objects.filter(Q(name__iexact=query) | Q(name__icontains=query))
```

or

```
results = Page.objects.filter(name__iexact=query)
```

Not working.The search is always case-sensitive. How to fix this? I am using Django 4.2.6 and Postgresql 14.9 on Mac m1 on Mac OS Ventura 13.4.1.

I want to filter my records by some string WITHOUT REGISTERING, for example a record with name "Apple" should be found by the strings "Apple", "apple", "aPPle", "ApPpLe" and so on.

Comment: What collation do you use for that column?